# ios traversing NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I'm having the darndest time getting the `text` out of

```
2012-01-27 16:04:32.113 My App[13112:207] {
    text = "\n    user@mail.net";
}
```

I can get this object fine by `NSLog(@"%@", [data objectForKey:@"EmailURL"]);`

I've tried `NSLog(@"%@", [[data objectForKey:@"EmailURL"] stringForKey:@"text"]);`

and I crash out with `SIGABRT` on `AppDelegate.h`

Comment: Please post some code - what are you assigning the value TO?  What is the sigabrt error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't have a `stringForKey:` method, you'll need to use `objectForKey:` again:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[data objectForKey:@"EmailURL"] objectForKey:@"text"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use NSDictionary's    `– valueForKey:`

Comment: @JacobRelkin "The key for which to return the corresponding value. Note that when using key-value coding, the key must be a string". While both work, this seems to be a bit more accurate as I already know for a fact that the "text" will be a string and not an object.

Comment: @Jackson `NSString` *is* an object.